# mediastreamsegmenter stops sending id3 metadata using HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, id3, mediastreamsegmenter

I am using a combination of `ffmpeg`and Apple's `mediastreamsegmenter` and `id3taggenerator` to create a HLS stream with metadata (ID3) embedded in it. I have all of the applications running and am able to retrieve the metadata out of the stream on the client side, but the issue is that after what seems like a random amount of time, the client stops receiving metadata on the stream.

Here is what I have working now:

This is the `ffmpeg` and `mediastreamsegmenter` part:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i udp://@:5010 -c:v libx264 -crf:v 22 -b:v 500k -preset:v veryfast -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -f mpegts - | mediastreamsegmenter -b http://localhost/stream -f /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/ -t 10 -s 4 -S 1 -D -y id3 -m -M 4242 -l log.txt
```

This is taking a udp stream on the localhost on port 5010 and encoding the video and audio to H.264 and AAC, respectively. It is pipping the MPEG-2 transport stream segments to the `mediastreamsegmenter`, which in turn is generating the `.M3U8` file and associated `.ts` files and placing them on a `NGINX` webserver. The `mediastreamsegmenter` is also listening on port 4242 for tcp traffic from the `id3taggenerator` which I will show how I am using it now:

```bsh
id3taggenerator -text '{"x":"12","y":"36"}' -a localhost:4242
```

As you can see, I am sending some simple x-y coordinates in JSON as text to the `mediastreamsegmenter` listening on port 4242. I am actually using a Python script to send some test data at the moment. Here is the script:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep

for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, 10):
        x = str(20 * i)
        y = str(20 * j)
        print("X: " + x + " - Y: " + y)
        call(["id3taggenerator", "-text", "{\"x\":\"" + x + "\",\"y\":\"" + y + "\"}", "-a", "localhost:4242"])
        sleep(1.0)
```

This script is just sending a bunch of x-y coordinates using the `id3taggenerator` CLI. I have adjusted the `sleep` amount from 0.1 to 15 and it doesn't seem to make any difference. The client application that is getting the metadata out of the stream only prints out anywhere from 4 to 35 points, but never has it ever received all of the x-y coordinates.

I am wondering if there is a limit to the amount of metadata that can sent per frame, but I cannot seem to find anything that specifies a hard-limit value for any of these tools...

Comment: Hi, im experiencing the exact same problem myself, did you ever find the cause or solution to this?

Comment: No, I never did. To be honest, I haven't looked into this in quite some time, but it sounds like it is still currently an issue. I ended up modifying the ffmpeg source code to listen for ID3 metadata directly and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: I've been thinking along those paths as well, you have any resources to share on how to modify ffmpeg in such a way?